# Create a simple time series

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to create a simple time series but I cant seem to figure out what is going on.
I am inputting a simple text tab delimited file as below:

```
        Date     Time             NOx.Levels
1       02/07/14 00:00:00         37

2       02/07/14 01:00:00         31

3       02/07/14 02:00:00         44

4       02/07/14 03:00:00         25
```

and I am using the code as follows:

```
 pollution_data <-read.table(file.choose(),header=T,sep="\t") 
 pollution_data

 dm <- ts(pollution_data, frequency=24, start=c(02/07/2014))
 dm$Date <- as.Date(dm$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")

 require(ggplot2)
 ggplot( data = dm, aes( Date, Visits )) + geom_line()
```

I  can't seem to get it to plot a simple time series.

Comment: `start=c(02/07/2014)` will not work.

Answer (score 3):

`ts` is not very good for date/time values.  Try the zoo solution below.  After that are some other solutions too.

Below `index = 1:2` means that the first two columns are the date/time, `format=` gives the percent codes for the format and `tz=` specifies the local time zone (which will also cause it to use POSIXct datetimes).  `autoplot` generates a ggplot2 plot.

```
Lines <- "       Date     Time             NOx.Levels
1       02/07/14 00:00:00         37
2       02/07/14 01:00:00         31
3       02/07/14 02:00:00         44
4       02/07/14 03:00:00         25
"

# 1    
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
fmt <- "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, index = 1:2, format = fmt, tz = "")
autoplot(z)
```

(continued after image)

[image]

These work too:

```
# 2
plot(z)

# 3
library(lattice)
xyplot(z)
```

Another way to do it is:

```
# 4
library(ggplot2)
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
DF$datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(DF$Date, DF$Time), format = fmt) # fmt defined previously
qplot(datetime, NOx.Levels, data = DF, geom = "line")
```

If we want to use `ts` its best to use hours here.  We assume the times start at hour 1 and each successive data point is the next hour.

```
# 5
plot(ts(DF$NOx.Levels), xlab = "hour")
```